# How to override Spring Boot health response codes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How to override actuator's default /health response status code based on its state:DOWN, UP, UNKNOWN so and so ? For example, if the health state is "UP", the response code should be 200. If DOWN: 400, unknown 300. Is there any work around to achieve this ?

Note: I do not want my own health endpoint. Instead, the existing one needs to be overriden .

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? Getting a 200 from `/health` does not mean that the service is healthy, it just means that the health check completed successfully. It is standard practice for consumers of that response to peek inside it in order to understand the health (or otherwise) of the service.

Comment: If you really must communicate the service's health in the form of HTTP status codes ... `400` means `BAD_REQUEST`, does it really make sense for 'DOWN` (which represents the state of something in the _server_) to be deemed a 'bad client request'? `300` is in the redirection grouping, does this really correspond to 'UNKNOWN'? How would you represent a failure in the health check itself? In other words; there is no clear, well understood mapping between UP/DOWN/UNKNOWN and HTTP status codes, this is one of the reasons why the /health endpoint returns a 200 and provides details in its payload.

Comment: @glytching . Thanks for answer. However above my codes are just to give an example. May be the response code can exist withing 2XX range.

Comment: Why I have to stick with response code is that my app is to connect with another tool and it ping the /health end point. that tool will proceed with the response codes provided by my app.

Comment: @glytching by default a 200 response means that the service is not known to be unhealthy. It will return 503 if it's known to be down.

Answer (score 11):

In Spring boot 2.x these are the built in status and their defaults, which you can override to the relevant code you want.

```
management.endpoint.health.status.http-mapping.UP=200
management.endpoint.health.status.http-mapping.UNKNOWN=200
management.endpoint.health.status.http-mapping.DOWN=503
management.endpoint.health.status.http-mapping.OUT_OF_SERVICE=503
```

or a custom mapping

`management.endpoint.health.status.http-mapping.DOWN=400`

or in yaml,

```yaml
management: 
   endpoint:
       health:
          status:
            http-mapping:
              UP: 200
              UNKNOWN: 200
              DOWN: 503
              OUT_OF_SERVICE: 503
```

In Spring boot 1.x these are the properties with custom status applied,

```
endpoints.health.mapping.DOWN=400
endpoints.health.mapping.UP=200
endpoints.health.mapping.UNKNOWN=300
```

or in yaml,

```yaml
endpoints:
   health:
      mapping:
         UP: 200
         DOWN: 400
         UNKNOWN: 300
```

[Spring Boot Current Actuator Health Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-health)

Answer (score 6):

The status codes are configured via [application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html). These are the defaults:

```yaml
management.health.status.http-mapping:
  UP: 200
  DOWN: 503
  OUT_OF_SERVICE: 503
  UNKNOWN: 200
```

For [Spring Boot 1.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) the property is `endpoints.health.mapping` instead.

It's a bad idea to use the codes you suggest, because they already mean other things. A reasonable change is to set `UNKNOWN: 500` if you want your upstream system to treat it differently to `UP`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#writing-custom-healthindicators) has been updated again (second time). The current properties for Health Check status mappings are:

```
management.health.status.http-mapping.DOWN=503
management.health.status.http-mapping.UP=200
```

Comment: Based on the current [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#writing-custom-healthindicators) the default for `DOWN` is 503.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `OUT_OF_SERVICE` and `DOWN` map to 503. Any unmapped health statuses, including `UP`, map to 200.

These values can be overridden as mentioned in other answers.